# Disable or silence DLC ads

Tags: killing-floor

I like to play games with my own music. Barring the odd terrible console port, this works out very well for me, because most games let me mute the in-game music. Killing Floor has an option to silence in-game music, but the ads you see when joining a server keep blasting their tunes regardless of that setting. Can I disable or silence these ads, so that I can enjoy my music properly?

Comment: I advise against any change of the games files since the game uses VAC.

Comment: @user28015 I hope there's a less intrusive solution to the intrusive ads problem.

Comment: @user28015: Modifying data files is safe.

Comment: What ads do you mean? First-party ads? As long as I've played (since early 2014) the game has only had *one* KF2 advertisement (autoplays video and audio), can be disabled by deleting the file in `\KillingFloor\Movies`.

Answer (score 1):

From the workshop, you can get lobby replacement videos. You should be able to just delete the relevant files as well.

The fact that this is on the workshop, and that I have done it myself many months ago makes me come to the conclusion that you won't get VAC banned for doing this.

When I first got a mod for this, it replaced all the adverts with the "Loadsamoney" song, and when they added the KF2 teaser trailer, it would sometimes play that. So I think that there is just a folder full of adverts (not at my computer right now to check) and you should just be able to delete all the adverts from there.